# Delegate didSet property of UIView not being called inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've been banging my head on the desk for the past 2 hours trying to figure this out so any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) (the develop branch) and I'm trying to place the `CalendarView` inside a custom UITableViewCell so I can make it look something like this:

[image: fullpixels]

The problem I'm facing is that it doesn't set the delegate property when I call `self.calendarView.calendarDelegate = self` inside the custom UITableViewCell

I know it's not being set because I've placed a `println` inside the delegate `didSet` property that's not being outputted.

Here is the CalendarViewDelegate outlet inside the CalendarView

```
// MARK: - Calendar View Delegate

@IBOutlet weak var calendarDelegate: AnyObject? {
    set {
        if let calendarDelegate = newValue as? Delegate {
            delegate = calendarDelegate
            println("delegate did set property called")
        }
    }

    get {
        return delegate
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the custom UITableViewCell I'm working with.

```
import UIKit

class CalendarCell: UITableViewCell {

    var calendarView: CVCalendarView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        selectionStyle = .None

        self.calendarView = CVCalendarView(frame: self.frame)
        self.calendarView.calendarDelegate = self
        self.calendarView.calendarAppearanceDelegate = self
        self.calendarView.animatorDelegate = self
        contentView.addSubview(calendarView)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    }
}
```

Here is my UITableViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class CalendarTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    var items = ["Apple", "Banana"];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myTableView.registerClass(CalendarCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(CalendarCell))
        self.myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func creatHeaderCell() -> UITableViewCell {
        var headerCell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NSStringFromClass(CalendarCell)) as! CalendarCell
        return headerCell
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            return 300
        }

        return 44
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 1
        default:
            return items.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            return self.creatHeaderCell()
        }

        let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Thomas"

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this line `self.calendarView = CVCalendarView(frame: self.frame)` is not attempting to set the calendar view to `nil` ? Your print statement in the setter would only be executed if the delegate is being set to something other than `nil`. Maybe `CVCalendarView(frame: self.frame)` is returning `nil` because the cell's frame hasn't been properly computed yet at the time it's instantiated and perhaps `CVCalendarView(frame: self.frame)` returns `nil` for a frame of zero size.

Comment: Hmm... I guess that can't happen since you'd then get a runtime error when attempting to set the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `println` statement is probably not reached because your if condition `if let calendarDelegate = newValue as? Delegate` is not true because what you pass in as `calenderDelegate` is a `CalenderCell`, not a `Delegate` or `CVCalendarViewDelegate` (typealias).

Additionally your `CalendarCell` does not conform to `CVCalendarViewAppearanceDelegate` and `CVCalendarViewAnimatorDelegate`.

You have to make your cell conform to those protocols to be able to set them as delegates.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more clear. I'm using code from the Develop branch. That's why my code differs

Comment: Okay, let me check that, but does not change the fact that the if condition will probably be evaluated to false

Comment: https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar/blob/develop/CVCalendar%20Demo/CVCalendar/CVCalendarView.swift

Comment: okay, the guy hosting the project should probably get his folders organized better, because why is the core code under `Demo`? ^^

Comment: And it does in fact not change the fact that your class needs to conform to the protocol `CVCalendarViewDelegate`!!!

Comment: I can't thank you enough. And I filled out an issue for the core code being under `Demo`